# UINavigationitem custom rightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

i have 2 custom right bar button items, and in portrait  mode they overlays each others and only one of them is visible, but on landscape mode both are visible. items are created with custom view which is the UIButton with background image.

```
optionsBUtton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[optionsBUtton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"optionsIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[optionsBUtton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"optionsBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[optionsBUtton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* btnOptions=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:optionsBUtton];

searchButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [searchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [searchButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"optionsBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [searchButton sizeToFit];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnSearch=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchButton]; 

rightButtonItems=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnOptions,btnSearch, nil];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItems=rightButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must user tool bar and set the toolbar with buttons here is example code

```
// create a toolbar where we can place some buttons
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];
[toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

// create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard save button
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
    target:self
    action:@selector(saveAction:)];
saveButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:saveButton];
[saveButton release];

// create a spacer between the buttons
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
    target:nil
    action:nil];
[buttons addObject:spacer];
[spacer release];

// create a standard delete button with the trash icon
UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
    target:self
    action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:deleteButton];
[deleteButton release];

// put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease];
[toolbar release];
```

Thanks..!

Comment: why use toolbar if there is button items collection property?

Comment: toolbar supports multiple buttons array to add toolbar and toolbar add to the navigationitem like below code self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease];

Comment: thanks Dinesh but i can't understand why use toolbar if there is a way to set items directly into navigationitem